# Refresh Mondrian views

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, roassal

I am trying to implement some visualizations using Mondrian in Pharo 3.0.

My main problem is that I do not find a way to dynamically update the Mondrian view: I am able to remove nodes doing

```
view removeAllEdgesTo: node;
     removeNode: node.
```

but I am not able to add nodes, change the layout and so on. I can  change the nodes and edges, but the view does not seem to be refreshed.

Another thing I want to do is the following: I have the user dynamically choose a subset of nodes and a color, and I would like to be able to change the color of these nodes.

Is there a way to interact with Mondrian views outside the builtin interactions?